# JavaMail handle read receipt of incoming messages

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am working on a mail client using JavaMail which is working fine. Now I want to be able to handle read receipts for incoming messages. If an incoming message header contains "Disposition-Notification-To" I want to handle it and send back read receipt just as thunderbird and other mail clients handle it. I've googled a lot and go through the JavaMail API but am only seeing sending messages with read receipt enable and not handling incoming messages requiring read receipts. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution for those who may have the same problem. I know the above answer reiterated going back to the API but did not provide a solution or an example and thus cannot accept it as answer to my question. Am doing this from Jruby but it should be easy to convert it to normal Java:

```
 m = javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.new(your_SMTP_obtained_session);
 m.setFrom(javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.new(from_who));
 m.setSubject("Message Receipt (displayed) - #{original_message_subject}");
 m.addRecipient(javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage::RecipientType::TO, 
    javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.new(destination_email_address));
 multireport = com.sun.mail.dsn.MultipartReport.new("Your text message to the" +
    "recipient i.e report content",com.sun.mail.dsn.DispositionNotification.new);
 m.setContent(multireport);
```

You now have a complete MimeMessage ready to be sent.